# Why does Springs OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider call the UserInfo Endpoint?

Tags: spring-security

I am having a hard time learning OAuth2 and OpenID Connect.
Every time I think I understand everything now, I come across another gimmick.
This time it's Spring Securities `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider`.

The `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider` is used instead of `OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider` if scope `openid` is not contained in requested scopes.

```java
if (loginAuthenticationToken.getAuthorizationExchange().getAuthorizationRequest().getScopes().contains("openid")) {
    // This is an OpenID Connect Authentication Request so return null
    // and let OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider handle it instead
    return null;
}
```

But why does this `AuthenticationProvider` load an `OAuth2User` via `UserInfoEndpoint`?

Isn't `UserInfoEndpoint` `OIDC` specific?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that OIDC defines a User-Info endpoint.

When using OAuth 2.0 to authenticate, there is still a need to figure out the user's information and so Spring Security publishes an interface (`OAuth2UserService`) that does that.

For non-OIDC implementations, I'd imagine that the `OAuth2UserService` is not pointed at an OIDC-compliant User-Info endpoint.

Comment: I can see the purpose of this Interface, but I don't understand why the default implementation `DefaultOAuth2UserService` requires an Endpoint to be set, that is not mentioned in the OAuth2 spec at all. Maybe the reason is that all OAuth2 providers have such an endpoint anyway. In ticket https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5659 someone says "The user-info-uri is required for standard OAuth 2.0 Providers (implemented by DefaultOAuth2UserService) but it's not mandatory for OIDC Providers (implemented by OidcUserService)." Maybe the implementation is meant, not the spec.

Comment: The reason `user-info-uri` is required for OAuth 2.0 Providers, but not for OIDC providers is because Spring Security can infer the `user-info-uri` for OIDC providers, since it can consult the spec to figure it out.

Comment: The fact that OAuth 2.0 does not mention user info URIs in the spec (meaning it's unspecified), is the reason that you must configure it. There's no way for Spring Security to know it otherwise since it can't derive the endpoint from the spec.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why Spring is does not use the user information from AccessToken but require something that is not necessarily existing. Maybe the reason is that all OAuth2 providers have such an endpoint anyway. I still don't see the need to require it by default.

Comment: That would assume that the access token is not opaque. OAuth 2.0 Clients typically don't get to inspect the access token as they are intended for use by the Resource Servers (thus the creation of the id token and OIDC)